# Where is '/host' declared for mount in Wubi (Ubuntu 9.10)?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, wubi

I'm using Wubi (ubuntu 9.10), and I couldn't find where '/host' mountpoint is declared for mounting. There's no entry in fstab, but it's listed in /proc/mount and mounted at boot time. Any ideas?

```
pedroel@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mounts

rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda1 /host fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/loop0 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
/dev/loop1 /home/pedroel/Downloads ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/pedroel/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/mapper/isw_efhafcifi_RAID_Volume01 /media/RAID_D fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

pedroel@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/pedro.disk /home/pedroel/Downloads               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 1):

It's specified as the "root device" - I'm guessing in GRUB's configuration, `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, or in the Windows bootloader (`C:\boot.ini` or `bootcfg`) - then mounted in the *initramfs*.